# Python: get files from 'specific' folders in S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The S3 bucket have in it multiple folders having in each an /In and /Out folders.

Example of folders in my `S3_BUCKET`:

```
MEMBER 1
├── In
├── Out

MEMBER 2
├── In
├── Out

MEMBER 3
├── In
├── Out
```

I want the get the list of files only in /In folders.

The following code is getting the list of all files in the S3 which is not the goal.

```
def pickup_s3_files():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('S3_BUCKET')
    reports = [obj.key for obj in bucket.objects.all() if not obj.key.endswith("/")]
    return reports
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add condition to check for `In` in key:

```
reports = [obj.key for obj in bucket.objects.all() if not obj.key.endswith("/") and 'In/' in obj.key]
```